# How can I configure zsh completion to show hidden files and folders?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

Currently when I invoke completion the behaviour is like this:

```
% cd ~/<TAB>
Completing directory
Desktop/    Downloads/  Pictures/   system/     Videos/
Documents/  Music/      Public/     Templates/  www/
```

How can I configure the completion to list the hidden files also?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could add `globdots` to `$_comp_options` in your `.zshrc` e.g.

```
.....
compinit
_comp_options+=(globdots)
.....
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to ignore the current directory (.) and parent directory (..)? They are often useless on a comp list.

Comment: @KrzysztofKaczor - Those are never shown in the completion list unless your `.zshrc` contains something like this: `zstyle ':completion:*' special-dirs true`  in which case they are listed so it's an easy fix ;)

Comment: thanks! turns out it's part of oh-my-zsh config.

Comment: One of the maintainers of Oh My Zsh said that [only `_comp_options+=(globdots)` is necessary](https://web.archive.org/web/20200926162627/github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/pull/4489#issuecomment-196992974). Do I really need `compinit`, too?

Comment: > Those are never shown in the completion list

dont be to sure. my zsh is showing them and i set special-dirs to `false`...

Comment: I don't know why but my config had `_comp_options+=(globdots)` and it was not working.  After changing it to `setopt globdots` it works.

Answer (score 30):

This is a zsh option. It is mentioned [in its introduction](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_16.html).

> GLOBDOTS lets files beginning with a . be matched without explicitly specifying the dot.

Add the following to your .zshrc file.

```
setopt globdots
```

Comment: I spent a long time searching for the corresponding option in my zsh config. I didn't know that ["Option names are case insensitive and underscores are ignored. For example, 'allexport' is equivalent to 'A__lleXP_ort'."](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zshoptions) and it was written `glob_dots` in my config.

Comment: This answer will affect parts of zsh other than tab completion. For example, `print *` will give you different results if you’ve run `setopt globdots`. For that reason, I would prefer the other approach (`_comp_options+=(globdots)`) unless you’re specifically sure that you want the effects of `globdots` everywhere.