# How can I configure zsh completion to exclude `.` and `..`?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I configured my zsh following this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/308315/how-can-i-configure-zsh-completion-to-show-hidden-files-and-folders). Then I found the completion now includes `.` and `..`. How do I remove them?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same question you provided has the answer:

According to a comment of [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/308322/414186)

> Those are never shown in the completion list unless your .zshrc contains something like this: zstyle ':completion:*' special-dirs true in which case they are listed so it's an easy fix

So you can use:

```bash
zstyle ':completion:*' special-dirs false
```